# Entry into Singapore with less than 6 months passport validity but more than 6 months long term pass validity

Tags: passports, singapore

Is the 6 months passport validity for Singapore strictly enforced for people on an LTVP (or other visitor pass) when the visitor pass is valid for more than 6 months?

My passport had ~5.5 months left before its expiration date, but I had an LTVP that was valid for well more than 6 months.

I didn't risk it and instead got a new passport before entering, but I'm curious what would've happened. I know that in some countries the 6 month validity is not a problem as long as you have a resident pass or visa, but Singapore might be stricter about this.

Answer (score 5):

From the official terms and conditions of the Long-Term Visit Pass:

> You are required to produce this LTVP and your **valid passport** to the Immigration Officer at the Checkpoint each time you leave Singapore and return during the validity of the LTVP.

So the passport must be valid at point of entry, but there are no further requirements on the Singapore side.

Source: https://www.ica.gov.sg/docs/default-source/ica/files/docs/terms_and_conditions_ltp.pdf

That said, airlines may not be aware of this since the LTVP is much rarer than the usual stamp-on-arrival Short Term Visit Pass, which does require 6 month validity, so I would suggest renewing your passport and transferring the LTVP before that mark.

Comment: mind the word LEAVE. So the passport needs to be valid on leaving Singapore as well as on entering. What the consequences of having an expired passport would be when trying to leave (apart from probably being barred from reentering) I don't know, but Singaporean law enforcement is notoriously strict. And of course any transit country towards your home country is going to be a risk as well and is likely to not let you in.

Comment: @jwenting It just means you have to renew the passport from embassy while in Singapore, if it expires during your stay. You can't leave with an expired passport anyway. The LTVP and other passholders can update the renewed passport details by themselves.

Comment: If it's only enforced on leaving, there would have been no problem because I could have made a new passport at the embassy in Singapore before leaving again. What I'm curious about is ENTERING on an expired passport + valid LTVP.

Comment: The airline gave me a choice of flying (taking all responsibility in case I'm denied entry) or rescheduling my ticket.

Comment: @martin You would almost certainly be refused boarding & entry on an expired passport.  Generally speaking expired passports can only be used to return to the country that issued them, and even that's quite tricky.

Comment: @lambshaanxy Not generally. For example, India won't allow to return with expired passport. You have to get to embassy and collect emergency travel document, or wait for passport to be renewed.

Comment: @AnishSheela Flying with an expired passport is indeed difficult in many countries, but are you saying India would turn away its own citizen at the land border if their passport is expired?

Comment: @lambshaanxy Nepal and Bhutan- no problem. China and Pakistan - They will stop before you get to reach India. Bangladesh - Not so sure.

Comment: This is not quite correct. Singapore Airlines would have let me board (based on my LTVP status) if I signed a waiver. My question is what would have happened at immigration.

Comment: It's also not true that this doesn't work elsewhere. Returning to Taiwan on an expired passport, for example, is perfectly fine as long as your ARC is still valid.

Comment: @jwenting I'm not sure. The phrasing is a bit ambiguous.
1. Present LTVP + passport when leaving
2. Return to Singapore before the LTVP expires

This is not the same as
Present LTVP + passport when leaving and entering.

It could still be sufficient to only have a valid LTVP on arrival.

Comment: @martin I don't think there's a country in the world that allows foreigners entry when they don't have a valid passport (unless there are special treaties in place where specific groups don't need a passport at all, like between Schengen countries). In fact most countries require your passport to be valid for at least a period after leaving, not just on entry.

Comment: @jwenting This is not always true if you are a resident of that country. I entered Taiwan on an expired (foreign) passport before (which I then renewed there). No issue at immigration because I had a valid residence visa.